# how to get error as object in subscribe of http get?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an asp.net core webApi and a Angular9 WebApp.

I want to get the error in a subscribe as object and not only as string.

```
this.http.post<TestSystem>(this.url, testsystem).subscribe((result) => {
   // do something
}, err  => {
    console.log(typeof err);
});
```

Th asp.net core backend returns

```
        [HttpPost(template: "save")]
    public ActionResult<TestSystemBean> Save(TestSystemModel model)
    {
        // Validate reportRequest
        if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            return BadRequest("Invalid ModelState");
        }
    }
```

But I only get the string 'Bad Request' and not an object to get the message 'Invalid Modelstate'.
How can I get the error as an object?

In the ErrorInterceptor in the AngularApp I get a full HttpErrorResponse:

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
  debugger;
  if ([401, 403].includes(err.status) && this.authenticationService.userValue) {
    // auto logout if 401 or 403 response returned from api
    this.authenticationService.logout();
  }
  const error = (err && err.error && err.error.message) || err.statusText;
  return throwError(error);
}))
```

}

Comment: Update angular full code here.

Comment: what's the value of err.error.message in your case?

Comment: @jkonst it was undefined, but I solve this yesterday

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. The line

```
const error = (err && err.error && err.error.message) || err.statusText;
```

in the ErrorInterceptor did some magic I don't understand, but remove this line and I get the HttpErrorResponse as I wanted it.